# What exactly is a 'logged in user'?

Tags: users

```
$ users
vorac


# Non-login shell, /root/.profile not sourced.
$ su
$ users
vorac

# Login shell, /root/.profile sourced.
$ su -
$ users
vorac
```

So we launch a login shell as another user in the last example, but still only the original user is 'logged in'. How is the concept of 'logged in user' defined?

Comment: The `login` binary (or equivalent) was never executed when you started those other shells.  Hence you never logged in again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix/Linux systems maintain a database of currently logged-in users, in the `/var/run/utmp` file (in some Unix variants there's also a parallel `utmpx` file, but they both serve the same purpose). The `login` program, which controls login on a physical console, the ssh daemon or GUI login programs for machines with X servers update information in that file when user logs in or out. `who` command reads information from that database.

The shell you start with `su -` is a "login" shell in sense that it behaves in the same way as the login shell started by the `login` program or ssh daemon (executes the same initialization files, etc.) but it does not record logins in `utmp` file, therefore you don't see these shells in the output of `who` command.

On the other hand, if you eg. start a `screen` session, `screen` records an entry in the `utmp` file and you can see the session in the output of `who` command.

Also, in some graphical DEs each new terminal window that you open is considered a new login and recorded in `utmp`, and in another ones not - there is only one main entry in `utmp` for the user being logged to the whole DE session. It depends on the terminal application of course.